# Find all starting indices in a string which are anagrams of a word

Tags: javascript, algorithm, strings, ecmascript-6, iterator

The task:

> Given a word W and a string S, find all starting indices in S which
>   are anagrams of W.
>
> For example, given that W is "ab", and S is "abxaba", return 0, 3, and
>   4.

My solution:

```js
    const anagramOccurrencesOf = (w, s) => {
      const occurrencesCopy = [];
      let sCopy = s.slice(0);
    
      let index = 0;
      while (sCopy.length && index !== -1) {
        index = sCopy.indexOf(w);
        if (index === -1) { break; }
        occurrencesCopy.push((occurrencesCopy[occurrencesCopy.length - 1] + index + 1 || 0));
        sCopy = sCopy.slice(index + 1);
      }
      const occurrencesReverse = [];
      let sReverse = s.split('').reverse().join('');
    
      index = 0;
      while (sReverse.length && index !== -1) {
        index = sReverse.indexOf(w);
        if (index === -1) { break; }
        occurrencesReverse.push( (occurrencesReverse[occurrencesReverse.length - 1] - w.length - index + 1) || s.length - w.length);
        sReverse = sReverse.slice(index + 1);
      }
    
      return [...occurrencesCopy, ...occurrencesReverse].sort((a,b) => a -b);
    };
    
    console.log(anagramOccurrencesOf("ab", "abxaba"));
```

EDIT: The solution above would find indexes of palindromes. The solution below should find indexes of anagrams:

```js
const sortAlphabetically = x => x.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('')
const getIndexOfAnagramIn = (s, w) => {
  const wSorted = sortAlphabetically(w);
  const result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length + 1 - w.length; i++) {
    if (sortAlphabetically(s.slice(i, i + w.length)) === wSorted) {
      result.push(i);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getIndexOfAnagramIn('abxaba', 'ab'));
```

Comment: Notice that anagrams are not only reverses. For a word `abc` there are 6 anagrams.

Comment: Ah, i mistook them with palindromes

Comment: Shouldn’t the example indices be: `0, 1, 3, 4, 5`?

Comment: Not from what I understood. Why do you think so? @morbusg

Comment: @thadeuszlay: well, the 4th index confuses me in the example as it is `ba`, but the 1st index would also be when backwards.

Comment: The b refers to the original string, therefore it’s the 4th index @morbusg

Comment: The word w is permuted but not the string a @morbusg

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a bit confused; a palindrome is a word, phrase, or sequence that reads the same backwards as forwards. `ba` isn't a palindrome, but `abba` would be.

Comment: Ah, are you talking about my first solution? If so, then just ignore my first solution. I misunderstood the term "anagram". The solution should be about anagrams not palindromes. @morbusg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code looks pretty good. I don't see much I would change. This code makes good use of `const` and `let` where appropriate.

The only thing that stands out is that splitting a string into an array can be done with the spread syntax instead of calling `split()`.

The first instance:

> ```
> let sReverse = s.split('').reverse().join('');
> ```

Could be changed to

```
let sReverse = [...s].reverse().join('');
```

And the other instance:

> ```
> const sortAlphabetically = x => x.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('')
> ```

Could be changed to:

```
const sortAlphabetically = x => [...x.toLowerCase()].sort().join('')
```